# How Split a String and add items to a ListView (for cycle/iteration) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, split

I have the next String in Eclipse

```
"actif,fernando,enrique" 
//this will be variable with commas
```

How split this String? and add to a list view with a "FOR"? in Eclipse / Android Java

I need ListView Or Spinner like this:

```
actif
_______
fernando
________
enrique
```

Comment: You don't add a ListView items in a for loop. You fill an adapter and then pass it to the ListView.

Comment: you can split the String using the split method - split(".");  store the values in an Array and inflate those array elements in the ListView.

Comment: @Shivam Chopra ... how can i do that?

Comment: @Adnan Ali replied the same... enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] list = "your string".split(",");
```

For listView:

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                yourListViewvariable.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Update for spinner:

```
private Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best Answer, because your code has efficiency and is easy! Very good!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
String input = "actif,fernando,enrique";

try {
    String[] splitArray = input.split(",");
    for(String s : splitArray){
        yourAdapter.add(s);
    }
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

}
```

Assuming that your adapter is of type `String`

Comment: In fact is my value is String, thanks